# How can I save a large video to the photo album?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetwriter

I have a streaming app that streams to a Wowza server, and I'm trying to implement a feature that saves the outbound stream to persistent memory. 
The examples I have been following (for saving to the photo album) add the video frames to a NSMutableArray and when there are no more frames to add, that array is shipped off to the photo album.

The problem is the things we stream are often hours long, and the local memory cannot support gigabytes of video, so we need a way to save to the hard drive without having the entire video in local memory first.

Is it possible to append video to an existing video in the photo album?
Are there any tricks that could simplify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use AVAssetWriter to save the video out to a file somewhere the app can write like the Documents directory. Then you can export that file to the photo album with [UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006894-CH3-SW41)